# Show VAT number in Checkout-page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, tax, vat

How to show `VAT number` in magento2 checkout-page.

Is there any option available in magento2 backend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you navigate to:

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > (Change
>   Scope to correct website/store view) > Create New Account Options >
>   Show VAT Number on Storefront
>
> Change dropdown to Yes.

You'll then have to set up your tax classes/tax rules/customer groups and then in the above section you can assign the correct values to the groups.

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/vat-validation-configure.html

Comment: How do I customize this VAT field require field validation based on country selected. I want to hide VAT field on USA and show VAT field with require validation for no USA country